# Prove that the scalar curvature is twice the value of the Gaussian curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

I would like to show that the scalar curvature $R$ is twice the value of the Gaussian curvature $K$:
$$R=2K.$$
I know that
$$R=g^{ij}R_{ij}=Kg^{ij}g_{ij}.$$
But somehow I don't know what's going on in the summation convention. Why do we have $g^{ij}g_{ij}=2$ instead of $g^{ij}g_{ij}=1$? Thank you.

Comment: $g^{ij} g_{ij} = \delta_{ii} = n$ Essentially you are taking trace of the identity matrix.

Comment: So $R=2K$ only holds for two-dimensional cases, like a surface? Thank you.

Comment: @Steve Yes, this is the case only for surfaces.

Comment: How stupid of me! Thank you guys.